# How can can I get replacement wood siding to match the existing siding?

Tags: repair, siding

I have some wood siding on my house that is rotting and crumbling away.  Here are some pictures of what I am talking about:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

What kind of wood is this?  If I buy new boards likely it is not going to match whatever I don't replace.  What can I do to make everything match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want everything to match, replace everything. Otherwise, you will always be chasing trying to immediately match the existing as other pieces of siding degrade in the future.

Painting sounds like an option, but in this case, we're talking about painting old wood some of which is reaching the end of its lifecycle. That means in a few years trying to match weathered paint instead of weathered wood...so probably repainting again.

One alternative is to relocate existing weathered pieces from a less visible location to any prominent location and to install the new wood in the less visible location. It makes the job slightly larger, but still smaller than replacing everything, painting, or artificially aging the new material.

As a note, the concrete slabs/pavers adjacent to the siding is probably contributing to the speed at which the siding degrades because water dripping off the roof will have more 'splash energy' after hitting the hard surface.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess is that's cedar, which should be easy enough to find at a home center or cedar dealer. It won't be gray like that when you purchase it but you can leave it outside untreated for a summer or two and it should gray up nicely. There are chemical "graying" agents that you could buy if your in a hurry but I generally find letting nature take its course is better. Looks like in the second picture your substructure might need a bit of attention too. Don't cover up rot or moisture or you'll be doing this again much sooner than you'd like. Cheers

Comment: So you are saying I should just replace it and let it weather naturally?  I was thinking about painting it.  Is that not advisable?

Comment: Painting it is fine but cedar takes some prep. Natural oils in the wood require a special primer, the guy/gal at your paint store can recommend one. And it still doesn't hurt to let it weather some first.

Comment: Should I power washing it before painting (or staining)?

Comment: **Do not power wash cedar!** It is a very soft surfaced wood and the spray from power washing can actually cut the board. While you *may* be able to get away with it using the gentlest nozzle, it is a big risk.